# How to send mail using different queues in new Symfony Mail component

Tags: symfony, symfony-mailer

I want to configure Symfony Mail component to send different types of emails using different queue priorities.
How can I do it?

So far I configured the queues:

```
framework:
    messenger:
        transports:
            async_low: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN_LOW)%'
            async_high: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN_HIGH)%'

        routing:
            'Symfony\Component\Mailer\Messenger\SendEmailMessage':  async_high
```

Then I started the queue with `async_high` being processed first:

```
bin/console messenger:consume async_high async_low
```

Now I would like to send one type of email form higher priority queue than the other:

```
$this->mailer->send($newsletterEmail); // 10.000 times
$this->mailer->send($resetPasswordEmail); // Triggered after newsletter
```

Without priorities the password reset would be sent after an hour (after all the newsletters get processed).
How can I send the newsletters using the lower priority queue?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to duplicate the `Message`, `Handler` and `Mailer`.